# Workflows/Processes triggered when updating the record in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, process, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm

I am facing a strange problem for which i couldn't find a proper solution on web. Though the similar question is asked on Microsoft Dynamics CRM forum under this [link](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/42493.aspx#.Udlcc20kzDM), but how to handle this situation is not mentioned there.

I have designed a Workflow in CRM 2011 which should trigger on a single field change (Application Stage) of the application as i have checked *Application Stage* field under *Start when: "Record fields change"*.

Now the problem is that workflow is triggering twice perhaps one through JavaScript code:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

And another through Update plugin on the same entity which is executed in response to JavaScript code above.

The workflow/process that i have designed is a kind of Master Workflow which has other sub processes that are initiated based on their respective *Application Stage*. Now in the child process i create an activity related to Application Stage and do other stuff but due to workflow initiation twice it is creating activity and doing other tasks multiple times.

What could be the viable solution to coup with this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

That JavaScript will definitely trigger the workflow once - it is no different from the user just clicking save.

A plugin which performs an update (e.g. `service.Update(...)`) will also trigger the workflow, that's all intended behavior.

I would start by looking at your plugin, mainly does it have to perform an update call? If you can avoid the double update that should solve your problem.

Did you know that a plugin can make data changes with an update call? If your plugin is registered synchronously and on the pre-event, then any change you make to the target entity object is reflected on the record, this doesn't trigger an additional update - its part of the original message.

For example, if the following code was registered on a pre-event, synchronous plugin the `'new_field'` would be populated with "My new value" and no additional update calls are required.

```
//get the entity 
Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

//set new field
entity["new_field"] = "My new value";

//end of plugin
```

Failing that it might be worth looking into other options:

1. If the plugin is setting the application stage, why is the JavaScript also setting it?
2. Is a plugin even required, could it all just go in a workflow?
3. May you could look at using a `do not run workflow` field, the field is set by the plugin/JavaScript then when the workflow runs if that field is set it does nothing, but clear the field (not really a recommended option).
4. Could the plugin trigger the workflows? Perhaps this could be read from a configuration record?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the plugin, when it triggers on Update, the context will only contain the fields that have changed.

Regarding a Javascript.. I think all the fields get sent to the context so it is like there is an udpate on all of them, so the workflow will fire.

The easiest solution would be to set up a flag on the record, so it only triggers once. This field could be a boolean named "flag" for example. At the beginning of the workflow you can check the value and let it continue depending on it.

For example:

- if (flag == false)

  - Do my logic...........
- set flag = true

What do you think?

Cheers,

Mario